# Trying to duplicate Click Event

Tags: android, onclick

Just made a button with a click event that opens a link to a webpage, on this layout there are multiple buttons. Now I want to duplicate the event of the first button to use it for the others as well. But when I duplicate the code and replace the names to the other button I get some errors. What is the problem?;

```
public class FourthFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fourth_layout, container, false);
    final Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://maurick.magister.net"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }

    });
    return view;

    final Button button3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
//a red line is showing line above
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://maurickcollege.net"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }

    });
    return view;

}
}
```

Comment: Isn't this android O.o

Answer (score 2):

Your first `return view` statements causes the method to return at this point.
So your code below this statement will not be executed. Your ide should show you the error message `Unreachable statement`.

To your two listeners:
create just one listener and set it to both views:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://maurickcollege.net"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
view.findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(listener);
view.findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two `return view` statements. 
That is making below code useless. That is the error

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using new OnClickListener,
Implement View.OnClickListener in your class,
which will create one common method for all click events

where do like this..

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_1:
        case R.id.button_2:
            //your common action goes here which will be executed for both buttons
    }
}
```